# Port is listening but cannot connect from remote

Tags: ubuntu, networking, port

I have a catalyst server running on a VM.

```
[info] Hello powered by Catalyst 5.90103                                                                                                                                             
HTTP::Server::PSGI: Accepting connections at http://0:3009/
```

And connecting within the VM

```
vagrant@precise32:/var/log/apache2$ curl 'http://localhost:3009'
DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
etc ...
```

The port seems to be listening

```
vagrant@precise32:/var/log/apache2$ netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:36300           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3009            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Connecting remotely I can see port 80 but not 3009

```
curl 'http://localhost:80'
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
curl 'http://localhost:3009'
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3009: Connection refused
```

I've seen similar threads but nothing has helped. This is iptables

```
vagrant@precise32:/var/log/apache2$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

And the firewall is turned off

```
vagrant@precise32:/var/log/apache2$ sudo ufw status  
Status: inactive
```

I'm very new at VM, I'm not sure if this is a hosts problem, an apache problem or a cataylst problem.  I did try running a python server and couldn't connect to that either.  All advice is much appreciated.  Thanks

EDIT - I've looked at similar posts, the general solutions there are not listening ports or firewall.  I don't think either applies here.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked at the post but it only gives advice on if the port isn't listening or the firewall is on, which doesn't apply to me as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Geo1986,  How are you supposed to connect remotely using `localhost`? Doesn`t the vm has an ip address to access it remotely?

Comment: I used vagrant to set it up - https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/networking.html.  In this case I'm using curl 'http://127.0.0.1:3009'.  I could be totally in the wrong direction here.

Comment: There could be a firewall between you and the box that is causng a problem. Did you use tcp dump to analyse it ?

Comment: When you are external to the vagrant box, localhost is the loopback address of the external device. Unless you have taken steps to forward the extrenalLoopbackAddress:3009 to the vagrant box then nothing is listening and you will get a connection refused message.

Comment: @Geo1986, the docs shows how to set up port forwarding from local to the vagrant box. Have you also set up a port forwarding for port 3009? May be it is not setup correctly.

Comment: You need somthing like `config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3009, host: 4567`

Comment: Thanks Iain, didnt spot these comments till I'd read bangals message.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: So, it is really a dupe :) noting is listening on localhost:3009.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access the app on vagrant box listening on port 3009, using address `localhost` remotely. For this to work, you need to setup the port forwarding correctly as mentioned in the vagrant doc: https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/networking.html

Check and make sure, it is setup correctly and that the request on `http://localhost:3009` is forwarded to the vagrant box. You should also make sure that your local firewall is not blocking connection to the port.

Comment: got it!  Needed to add to the VagrantFile

    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3009, host: 3009

Thank you!